# Image Hover effect CSS. I want my images to look like this: https://www.medi360.in/NewHome/Our_Specialists.html

Tags: html, css

For some reason, my CSS styling is not working. You may notice the #content in each of the CSS styling options. That is because I only wanted these styles to apply to a certain section of my website. I looked online and used the W3Schools resource, yet for some reason, it still doesn’t work. My images do not have the hover effect. I want my images to look like these:
https://www.medi360.in/NewHome/Our_Specialists.html

```
#content.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 }
  #content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
 #content .column{
 float:left;
 width:33.33%;
 padding:5px;
 }
 #content .row::after{
 content: "";
 clear:both;
 display:table;
 }

 #content .overlay {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: transparent;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;

 transition: background-color .5s ease;
 border-radius:50%;
 }
 
 #content .overlay:hover {
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #008CBA;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;
 transition: background-color .5s ease;
 }
 #content.text {
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 }
```

```
<div id="content">
      <!-- main container-->
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row sidebar-page">
          <!-- Page Content -->
            <div class="col-lg-12 page-content">

                <!-- Classic Heading -->
                <!--first image -->
                <div class="col-lg-12 div-gap-padding">
                  <div class="container">            
                    <div class="column">
                        <div class="team">
                            <div class="img">
                                <img src="/static/img/team/team-1.jpg" alt="" style="width: 200px;">
                                <div class="overlay">
                                  <div class="text"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="team-prof">
                                <a href="#">Dr. Pawan Kumar Kesari</a>
                            </h3>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply an id="" or class="" to the img element itself, and set the border-radius of that class or id to 50%, then you can set the hover attribute of the element above it to respond and change color when you hover over that. since you're aligning the image to the element that changes color, the element that changes on hover should have the hover attribute.

Comment: I think .img needs to be position relative as well for the overlay size to be correct

Comment: I am a little confused by the second part of the explanation. What do you mean by "setting the hover attribute of the element above it to respond....."?

Comment: @RahulGanesh, the element that contains the "overlay" element should have the :hover, and also change color. You are mousing over the "overlay" class, therefore, it should be the element that is coded with :hover in the css.

Comment: ohh I see, thanks for explaining to me. Ok, so I tried that and for some reason, nothing happened. Let me post my changes of the code to here.

Comment: @RahulGanesh also: adding ":hover" to the element in the html doesn't work, because ":hover" is something that is responsive in css, it should only exist in the css document because the browser searches the css for the answer to "what happens if the user hovers over this thing?" the css says"when the user hovers over this, change the background"

Comment: Ok, so like the hover is only in the css because the css is where all the styling happens and the html will look there to see what will happen if you hover? Let me update my code n

Comment: Ok, that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

For clarification:

```
 #content.container {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
 }
  #content img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
 }
 #content .column{
 float:left;
 width:33.33%;
 padding:5px;
 }
 #content .row::after{
 content: "";
 clear:both;
 display:table;
 }


 #content .overlay {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: transparent;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;

 transition: background-color .5s ease;
 border-radius:50%;
 }
 #content .overlay:hover {
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%;
 opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: #008CBA;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 100%;   border-radius:50%;
 transition: background-color .5s ease;
 }
 #content.text {
 color: white;
 font-size: 20px;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
 text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Ok, I am just confused why there is 2 overlays now. Again, I am sorry If im asking really stupid questions, I am not that experienced.

Comment: @RahulGanesh the first #content .overlay{} is the element when the user is *not* hovering over it. the second, #content .overlay:hover{} is what the css is telling the browser to display when the user hovers over anything with the .overlay class.

Comment: Ok, I guess that makes sense. I updated my code, but for some reason, there is no changes still. My updated code is on this post

Comment: @RahulGanesh remove the #content identifier from anything that's not the #content element itself. Is there a link to this project that's functional?

Comment: Here is the link: (https://rotaryweb.herokuapp.com/) I need the team section to have hover effects like the website I provided. The github link is: https://github.com/Boastriker/Internship.git. Btw, ty for helping me out!